# Set an alternate baseline grid in an InDesign document, different to the rest of the document

Tags: adobe-indesign, grids

Baseline grids in InDesign are set on a per-document basis, in preferences. What if I need a different baseline grid somewhere in a document?

Can I override the document baseline grid in one section, frame, page or master page?

For example, you might want a different baseline grid to the rest of a document on a contents page, a references block, or on a master page that is used for a very different type of content e.g. photo spreads with side captions.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I can tell, the only place you can override the document's baseline grid and set a different baseline grid is at the **text frame** level.

[image]

There are a few ways to do this:

- **As a one-off:** select a text frame, then `Text Frame Options` > `Baseline options`
- **For a class of text frames:** in the `Object Styles` window, create an Object Style, then set the new baseline grid for everything with this style in `Text Frame Baseline Options`
- **For everything on a page:** the only way I can find that prevents multiple frames becoming misaligned to each other is to give everything on one page a common object style with a custom baseline grid set to `Relative to: Top of page`
- **For a master page:** I can't find anything specific to master pages. The most reliable way seems to be the same as pages: have all frames on your master page use a shared object style with a custom baseline grid, set to be relative to the page

For very complex documents, with long sections needing different grids, you could also consider [setting it up as a book](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/creating-book-files.html) with different InDesign documents for different sections.